# : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /demo/public_html/demo/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Tags: php

> Warning: include(/home/swagjewelers/public_html/demo/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/swagjewelers/public_html/demo/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Comment: This error is self descriptive, what answer do you expect?

Comment: You are missing some files that are included to your page. Check your filepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `(/home/swagjewelers/public_html/demo/application/views/errors/html/error_php.ph` doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Usual case - Your web server has no access to this file.

Try this:

```
chmod o+r /home/swagjewelers/public_html/demo/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php
```

By this command you will give other system users reed access to this file.